# Customer quote does not exists after product save from the backend

Tags: magento2.4, quote, magento2.4.4

I am facing the one issue in local. while saving the product from the back end customer quote does not exists getting the error in report log

Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path","1":"#1 Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Interceptor->getQuote() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php:222

please suggest what is the issue on live its working fine.